# Listing multiple files in a specific format in BASH

Tags: linux, bash, sorting, stat

I have lots of files in a directory and I want to list all files in a specific format by creating date order (newer files first)

I can do this with `stat` and `sort` in the directory of files:

Commands:

```
cd /path 
stat -c '%.19y %n' * | sort -nr
```

Output:

`2014-01-25 16:44:52 Filename1.txt
2014-01-24 16:34:17 Filename2.txt`

It is fine. This is what I want exactly.

But when I try to run outside of the directory, command shows filenames with **/path**

Commands:

```
cd / 
stat -c '%.19y %n' /path/* | sort -nr
```

Output:

`2014-01-25 16:44:52 /path/Filename1.txt
2014-01-24 16:34:17 /path/Filename2.txt`

How can I list file names without path?

Comment: Why can you not use `cd /path/`?

Comment: because i want to use this as crontab entry or shell script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided you have GNU find, you can use that instead

```
find /path -printf '%TY-%Tm-%Td %TH:%TM:%.2TS %f\n'

2015-10-12 04:54:24 file
```